# Performing df.map() or df.merge() against a single <str> value to return a <float>

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a list of 5 letter words in a pandas dataframe, which splits the word into different columns and assigns a value to each letter, then performs a summation of the values. The following code imports a .json dictionary and assigns values to a letter:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]


j = open('words_dictionary.json')
dictionary = json.load(j)

dictionary_db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Word'])
letter_db = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Letter'])

word_count = 0
num_word_count = 0
letter_count = 0

for i in dictionary:
    word_count += 1
    if len(i) == 5:
        dictionary1_db = pd.DataFrame({i}, columns=['Word'])
        dictionary_db = pd.concat([dictionary1_db, dictionary_db], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
        num_word_count += 1
        split_word = split(i)
        L1 = split_word[0]
        L2 = split_word[1]
        L3 = split_word[2]
        L4 = split_word[3]
        L5 = split_word[4]

        for s in split_word:
            letter_count += 1
            letter1_db = pd.DataFrame({s}, columns=['Letter'])
            letter_db = pd.concat([letter_db, letter1_db], ignore_index=True, axis=0)

grouped = letter_db.groupby('Letter').value_counts()
grouped_db = pd.DataFrame(grouped, columns=['Value'])
grouped_db = grouped_db.apply(lambda x: (x/num_word_count)*.2, axis=1)
grouped_dict = grouped_db.to_dict()
```

Resulting in a grouped_db of:

|  | Letter | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 0.10544 |
| 1 | b | 0.02625 |
| 2 | c | 0.03448 |
| .. | .. | .. |

as well as a similar dictionary:

```
grouped_dict = {'a': 0.10544, 'b': 0.02625, 'c': 0.03448, ...}
```

My problems start to occur when I try to map the string value to the float value.

**How would I go about either merging a float value to the specified letter key or mapping a dictionary float value to the specified letter key without causing an 'NaN' value error?**

*ATTEMPT 1:*

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'L1': 'a'}])
df['L1Val'] = df['L1'].map(grouped_dict)
```

df:

|  | L1 | L1Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | nan |

intended df output:

|  | L1 | L1Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | .10544 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*; we don't care about your level of expertise, but we *do* care about having a *clear, thought-out* question. If you are trying to figure out *how you want to approach the problem*, this is probably not the right web site. That said, I can't understand *what the actual question is*. Specifically: when you run the code, *what is supposed to happen that doesn't already happen*? What do you mean by "perform any logic", and what *problem are you trying to solve* with the mapping?

Comment: Edited to improve clarity of the question

Comment: Try this: df['L1Val'] = df['L1'].map(grouped_dict). If you still see an error, please update your question with this attempt and the error message.

Comment: Shown in Attempt 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the both dataframes as follows:

```py
df.merge(grouped_db, left_on="L1", right_on="Letter")
```

The columns L1 and Letter will be redundant but you can filter one out afterwards.